# The type 'Span<char>' may not be used as a type argument

Tags: c#, .net-core

I tried to declare a list of spans like this:

```
public List<Span<char>> spanList;
```

But looks like I can't do this as the error says **The type 'Span' may not be used as a type argument**.

So, what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Span<T> is a `ref struct`. That means it is a **stack-only value type** (see here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2018/03/02/c-7-series-part-9-ref-structs/). Hence why you cannot use it for/in something (like a list) that ultimately lands on the heap...

Comment: Ok, thanks. No alternative then.

Comment: If we are supposed to provide an alternative solution, we need to know the actual problem. What do you need to use the Span and List for?

Comment: @elgonzo: That seems like an answer to me...

Comment: Still doesn't explain why you can never use it as a type argument. The type may only be used in contexts where it's allowed to use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As an alternative you can create `List<Memory<char>>`. Then you can acquire a `Span<char>` for the individual elements:

```
var someCharArray = "abcdefghij".ToCharArray();

Memory<char> memory1 = someCharArray;
var memory2 = memory1.Slice(1, 3);

var list = new List<Memory<char>> { memory1, memory2 };

// ...

var span1 = list[0].Span;
var span2 = list[1].Span;
```

However, we'd really need to know your use case to be able to tell if this all is useful for you.

By the way, I recommend [this article on the topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814808.aspx). After reading it carefully, you'll be able to decide that the code above makes sense or not in your use case.

Comment: I have a function that accepts `ReadOnlySpan<float> probs` as argument, and I want to assert it is not null. I get the same error. The argument comes from a buffer that I then pass the span to this function.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to declare a list of spans like this:

```
public List<Span<char>> spanList;
```

That's not legal.

> But looks like I can't do this as the error says The type 'Span' may not be used as a type argument.

Correct.  Spans may not be used as type arguments.

> what am I doing wrong?

You're using a span as a type argument. That's not legal. That's why the error message says that spans may not be used as type arguments.

Since you already knew that, it's not clear why you asked the question. What are you really asking here?

Spans are *very special types* that exist for *very specific purposes*. If you're trying to put a span in a list, you are doing something very wrong because you are working directly against the intended purpose of a span. Spans exist to give you better performance in some very limited scenarios, and **the price you pay for that better performance is limitations on how you can use spans**.

This sounds very much like what we call an "XY" problem. You have a problem, you have a crazy idea of how to solve it, the crazy idea does not work, and now you're asking a question about the crazy idea instead of the real problem.  Ask a question about the real problem.

> Any alternative?

Either make a list of something other than a span, or manage your spans using something other than a list.

**Since we don't know what problem you are attempting to solve, we cannot help you solve it.**  We don't know what problem you're trying to solve because **you didn't say what problem you're trying to solve**.  Help us help you.

All we know so far is that you've tried to do something illegal, and then asked a question about the error message, which clearly says that what you're doing is illegal.

Comment: Here's an actual problem I needed to solve: I had a function that returned a Span<T>, then later needed to have it return a pair of them. Obvious thing was to return (Span<T> a, Span<T> b) but that gives a confusing error that led me to this SO page. I suppose an "auto-detect-as-ref-struct anonymous tuple" language feature would resolve this. (My current alternative is to `out` the spans instead.)